# angular 2 synchronous load

Tags: angular, typescript, httprequest

I have an JWT token in my locale or session storeage which holds the userId.

So if the user refreshes on a route like

test.com/route2

the **app.components.ts** fetches the roles with a http request

```
    constructor(
    private userService: UserService
   )
  {
    this.userService.getUser(this.subId()).toPromise().then((data)=>{      this.setLoggedUser(data);
});
  }
```

So the problem is now on my ngInit event of Route2, which is **route2.component.ts.**
Im doing a http request which fetches customers, but the problem is it is fired before the LoggedUser is set and it throws null error.

```
   this.groupService.getAllCustomersOfGroup(this.getLoggedUser().Group.Id).subscribe(
  data => this.customers = data,
  err => this.error(err),
  () => { this.loadingHideSucces(); }
);
```

Comment: There are no synchronous requests. You just need to properly chain async calls, by returning an Observable others can subscribe to. There are several tutorials out there that show how to use observables with Angular ([Google search](https://www.google.at/search?q=angular2+observable&oq=angular2+obser&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i60l2j69i65j69i57j69i59.2092j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

Comment: with topromise,await and async (ES2016?) it is, but not in the constructor idk why

Comment: `await` and `async` doesn't make anything sync. It's still the same async. It's just more convenient syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to chain your calls to fetch your data in the right order, for example you could implement your `getLoggedUser()` method to return an `Observable` :

```
ngOninit() {
  this.getLoggedInUser().switchMap(user=>{
    this.groupService.getAllCustomersOfGroup(user.Group.Id).subscribe(
        data => this.customers = data,
        err => this.error(err),
        () => {
            this.loadingHideSucces();
        }
    );
  })
}

getLoggedInUser():Observable<LoggedInUser>{
 // logic to fetch user data, returns an observable.
}
```

As your component is named "route2" I guess it is used in a `ng-router-outlet` tag and then you could also use a [Resolve guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard).